# How is this Flash video playable on mobile devices [using JWPlayer]?

Tags: html, flash, video, jwplayer, flv

I'm trying to make my anime-streaming website FLV videos playable on mobile device, so I changed the technology I'm using from flash to **HTML5 MP4, webM and OGG**.

But while I'm surfing this site - which is using **jwPlayer** - from my Android device:
**[Here](http://video.kooora.com/media/267064)**

I found that the video is working well although it is using **FLV**?

Can anyone explain how this could happen?

Comment: This is a Flash video player that's playing an FLV file (the native Flash video format). What is special about it?

Comment: I tried to use flowplayer to play FLV videos, but unfortunately they are not playable on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature of JWplayer. It will detect when Flash is not supported and switch to HTML5.

This is from their website:

> JW Player is tested on the world’s most popular desktop browsers to
>   ensure the best playback experience for your viewers. From IE8 to the
>   latest version of Chrome, on Windows and OS X we ensure that any user
>   can watch your content. JW Player always selects the best playback
>   mode for your media behind the scenes.

http://www.jwplayer.com/products/jwplayer/html5-and-flash/

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But when I inspected the video page, I did not find but the flv file. ie. no mp4 or webm files ?

Comment: Have you inspected the webpage from your computer or from your mobile phone?

Comment: From PC ..
How can I make sure that mobile version is different ?

Comment: Even examining the page on a PC, I'm seeing an MP4 fallback file, labeled as "hlsURL." Clearly, if Flash isn't available, they're dropping back to that MP4.

Comment: Try this to inspect the website from your android device: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Does your Android device have Flash installed?

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer
Yes, it has flash installed.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that the video is working well although it is using FLV ?!
>   Please, can anyone explain how could this happen ?

Are you saying FLV because it is Flash? Did you know Flash itself can play MP4 files anyway? Looking at the source code I see MP4 video files provided so I think they are just using Flash Player app to play MP4 files where plugin is available or else then using HTML5 for mobile etc.

Test by disabling Flash Plugin in mobile browser settings, you should now see an HTML5 player instead for handling exact same file that Flash app was playing.

So to answer : **How is this Flash video playable on mobile devices [using JWPlayer]?**
You have a mobile with Flash Plugin installed and you visited a page that had a video player app made with Flash to play some MP4 files. Your mobile is flash capable so it worked and you watched some MP4 file using a Flash decoder instead of an HTML5 decoder.